# How do I store a Cassandra table solely in descending date order?

Tags: cassandra-2.0

I have a table that stores millions of url, date and name entries. Each row is unique in terms of either:

```
url + date
```

or

```
date + name.
```

I require this table to be stored in descending date order so that when I query it I can simply "SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 1000" to get me the most recent 1000 records, no sorting involved. Does anyone know how to set things up to do this please? To the best of my current understanding I am trying the following but it does not store them in date order:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
url text,
date timestamp,     
name text, 
PRIMARY KEY ((url, name), date)
)
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (date DESC);
```

Comment: If you will not query on the url and the name , I don't think is a good idea to define them as a partition key, I'll choose date (timestamp UUID )

Answer (score 0):

To store the data according to an order, you'd need to change the partitioner to byte ordered. This is no longer a good idea...it's maintained for back compat, but there are issues:

http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/architecture/architecturePartitionerBOP_c.html

You could also apply bucketing and query over your buckets. Each bucket being a partition, and each partition would have data stored in order. Not exactly what you want, but worth trying.